# SQL Help - Join small lookup table where not all columns are required (and an other option)

Tags: sql, join

I have one large table with transactions and a smaller lookup table with values I want to add based on 4 common columns. The trick here is not every combination of these 4 columns will exist in the lookup table and there are scenarios where I want it to stop checking and accept the match instead of going to the next column. I also have an "Other" option to default to if it doesn't match any of the options.

Table structures are something like this:

```
transaction_table
country, trans_id, store_type, store_name, channel, browser, purchase_amount, currency

lookup_table
country, store_name, channel, browser, trans_fee
```

The data could be something like this:

```
transaction_table:

country| trans_id| store_type  |store_name  |channel |browser |amt  |currency
US     | 001     | Big Box     | Target     | B&M    |N/A     |1.45 |USD    
US     | 002     | Big Box     | Target     | Online |Chrome  |1.79 |USD   
US     | 003     | Small       | Bob's Store| B&M    |N/A     |2.50 |USD   
US     | 004     | Big Box     | Walmart    | B&M    |N/A     |1.12 |USD   
US     | 005     | Big Box     | Walmart    | Online |Firefox |3.79 |USD   
US     | 006     | Big Box     | Amazon     | Online |IE      |4.54 |USD   
US     | 007     | Small       | Jim's Plc  | B&M    |IE      |2.49 |USD 

lookup_table:
country|store_name  |channel |browser |trans_fee
US     |Target      |B&M     |N/A     |0.25   
US     |Target      |Online  |        |0.15
US     |Walmart     |        |        |0.30
US     |Other       |        |        |0.45
```

So looking at the lookup_table data:

- Row 1 is very specific and would be a match on all 4 of the join
  columns.
- Row 2 would not care what browser was used to shop at Target so
  regardless of the "browser" value, the trans_fee should come back
  the same (other stores may care though).
- Row 3 is saying any transaction with a country='US' and the
  store_name='Walmart', regardless of the rest of the join columns
  would have the same trans_fee
- Row 4 is the "other" scenario where it should look first at the
  store_name column and if it doesn't find a match, go to Other.

The lookup_table data can change and may end up being time dependent (start_date and end_date columns added) so it really wouldn't be a good candidate for a long, complex CASE statement.

I was thinking of a combination of checking each column with an IF IN statement but I'm hoping there's a more straightforward conditional join type statement I can use to go column by column and have an other option.

Thanks!

edit: I didn't specify this but I want to basically return all of the data from transaction_table and add the corresponding trans_fee to each line.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a conditional JOIN.

Something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM lookup_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction_table
ON CASE WHEN lookup_table.store_name IS NOT NULL 
THEN transacton_table.store_name = lookup_table.store_name END
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was thinking the same thing but found [this](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/04/03/conditional-joins/) blog talking about using outer joins and coalesce instead to not bog down the query. My actual base table is fairly large so query performance is something I"m worried about.

Answer (score 0):

Such partial matching is tricky.  And your problem is not really that well set up.  You seem to have `NULL`s in some columns and general values in others.

In any case, you can solve this by matching what you can and then using `order by` to get the best match.  In your case, I think this looks like this:

```
select tt.*,
       (select trans_fee
        from lookup l
        where l.country = tt.country and
              l.store_name in ('other', tt.store_name) and
              (l.channel = tt.channel or l.channel is null) and
              (l.browser = tt.browser or l. browser is null)
        order by (case when l.store_name = tt.store_name then 1 else 2 end),
                 (case when l.channel = tt.channel then 1 else 2 end),
                 (case when l.browser = tt.browser then 1 else 2 end)
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as trans_fee
from transaction_table tt;
```

This is generic SQL.  But the same idea should work in any database.

Comment: So I realized that I didn't state that we're looking to do this in Hive before and I'm learning today that I can't use a subquery in the select (can only be in the from). Thinking if there's a way to shift this into a stand-alone sub-query and union it...